How should I put the pauses in beamer to see elements in the list in different order?
\begin{frame}
\begin{eqnarray*}
This sentence should be seen in the second place.  $A$
This sentence should be seen in the first place.   $B$
This sentence should be seen in the third place.   $C$
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{frame}

My question is about how should I put the pause between sentences. Roughly speaking, I want to see first the letter $B$. After a click, I want to see $A$ and $B$ as a pairs, one under the other. Again after a click, I want to see $A,B$ and $C as a triples.
Basically,
B
A 
B
A
B
C

do you want sentences with $A$ or do you want an eqnarray (and your sample output doesn't match either)?

I want to write sentences in eqn array with this order?

You can't do this with \pause, if that's what you're asking. You need e.g. \only etc. The environment is meant for an array of equations - not sentences. Why don't you use a tabular?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thanks for your helping. @cfr where should I put \only?

I don't know because I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you have three sentences? Three sentences together with an inline maths character for each sentence? Three equations? Three maths characters? You say something like e.g. \only<2->{text} to have text show on the second and later slides.

These are the equations $x^4+13, x^5+13, x^6+13$. I want audience should see the second equation (in the middle one). After I click, they should see $x^4+13, x^5+13$ together. And after a last click they should see all of them.

eqnarray is entirely unsuitable for writing sentences and the $ in $A$ would generate errors so your example does not help anyone understand your question.

Actually, I want to write equations not sentences. What do you suggest for them?

You should provide a more useful example, not one that generates multiple unrelated errors such as using $ in an eqnarray which makes it completely unusable as a basis for answers. You can use what I posted, deleting the text and putting the whole equation in the $....$ there would be other math specific options but that is fine.


Just specifying \only for each overlay on which the text should appear
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \mbox{\only<2->{This sentence should be seen in the second place.  $A$}}
  
  \mbox{This sentence should be seen in the first place.   $B$}

  \mbox{\only<3->{This sentence should be seen in the third place.   $C$}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}


That is exactly want I want. Thank you sir.

You could remove the \mbox  if you'd use \uncover instead of \only

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I remembered there was such a command but not what it was called, and obviously reading the documentation was not an option. (but thanks)

@DavidCarlisle ... all the easy to remember command names, like \put, were probably already taken :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and \frame

@DavidCarlisle latex should have anticipated that a future class might want to use this name :)
